# Trying to find the name of a fantasy book I read in the 90's

Tags: story-identification

I have almost nothing to go on...  I vaguely remember the villain's name starting with a k, and maybe something about a skull.  The villain's name might also start with an s, and have a k in the name, and be what's making me think of a skull.  At the end of the book the main character, who is either a man or boy, has to disguise his thoughts about somebody because the villain is asking him about them, and can sense his thoughts or read his mind.  It seems like he pictures a girl riding somewhere on a horse.  I'm pretty sure there were some sci-fi elements as well as fantasy.  I think it was a series, and that the book I'm thinking of may have been the fourth one.  For some reason I thought the books were by Ursula k leguin, but none of them seem to match.  I have a vague memory of the villain being called a warlock, or a warlord?  And something about a bird...either he could he change into a bird, or use a bird to spy on people.  Not completely sure about that but that's all I've got!

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: Is it possible it might be from the Witch World series? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witch_World

Comment: Parts of the question made me think immediately of the Fionavar Tapestry - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fionavar_Tapestry, I read these years ago.  Perhaps the villains name beginning with K was mixed with the author Guy Gavriel Kay?  I think the ending is similar iirc.

Comment: I don't think it's any of the Witch World books...but something along those same lines.  It's for sure not the Fionavar Tapestry.  Thanks though!

Comment: I found myself wondering about Christopher Stasheff's stories about the Gallowglass family, which began with *The Warlock in Spite of Himself.* That has a certain mixture of "magic" and "science," with many (but not all) of the witches and warlocks in the stories having "psychic" abilities to provide a pseudo-scientific explanation of their incredible powers (telepathy, telekinesis, etc.), but with honest-to-goodness magic popping up from time to time (parallel universes, and all that). Can't swear that I remember one with a boy having visions of a girl riding on a horse, though.

Comment: It's not Stasheff's books.  Thanks though!

Comment: Possibly Janny Wurts' "Cycle of Fire" trilogy? Your description sort of reminds me of it.

Comment: It's not Cycle of Fire..although those sound cool I think I'll check them out.  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Far from an exact match but with inexact details it might worth looking at The Saga of the Exiles series by Julian May. Strictly speaking its science fiction but with a lot of very fantasy style imagery, psyche powers, a character who transforms into a raven, four books in the series, (the last one is called The Adversary), lots of names with K and S, horses and horse riding, published in the mid 80s so definetly fits the time line.

Answer (score 2):

It could be the last book of David Eddings' *The Belgariad* series, [*Enchanters End Game*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/44687.Enchanters_End_Game?from_search=true) - It fills a number of your requirements:

1. The villain's name is **K**al Torak
2. The main character, an upper teens boy, is trying to confuse the villain (who is trying to enter his mind) with thoughts of his (future) wife - who, in other scenes, is riding a horse.
3. This is the 5th book out of 5, not the 4th...but close.
4. One of the other main characters will often shapeshift into the the form of an owl.

Even if it isn't what you were thinking of - I recommend the series, they're fun and easy fantasy reads.

Comment: It's definitely not Enchanter's End Game...  I did a quick read through to be sure.  The book I'm thinking of is a sci-fi and fantasy hybrid.  Thanks for the suggestion anyway!

Answer (score 0):

In le Guin's Earthsea series the name the wizard Ged uses is Sparrowhawk, in the first book, one of the things they learn is seeing trough the eyes of a bird. In Tombs of Atuan he and the priestess have to hide their thoughts from the "gods" she used to serve. In Furthest shore he has to hide his thoughts from the eldest dragon named Kalessin, and later from Cob, and I'm not sure, but he might have had a flashback of the girl riding on a horse, so maybe your original thought was correct?